# converting methods error message

Tags: java

I get this message for the last part of this code for "cost",

> The method toDoubleString(double, boolean) in the type Convert is not applicable for the arguments (Double, int),

not sure how to fix this. if i take it out i get this message,

> The method toLeftPaddedString(String, int) in the type Convert is not applicable for the arguments (Double, int).

Help, thanks.

```
public String printSummaryOutput() {
    return Convert.toRightPaddedString(make, 8) + printSummaryOutput() +  
               Convert.toRightPaddedString(model, 11) + Convert.toLeftPaddedString(color, 6) + 
               Convert.toLeftPaddedString(purchaseDate, 10) + Convert.toLeftPaddedString(Convert.toDoubleString(cost, 10));
}
```

Comment: Did you read the message? What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: `toDoubleString` expects a **boolean** as second argument, not an integer. You are passing `10` instead of `true` or `false`. Same for the other method(s). Solution: Don't pass an integer or correct the method signature (if you wrote it).

Comment: Improve the title of this post to explain the problem - that way people will click on it.

Comment: ok yes, i'm writing the code. but i'm also using a template from the professor. anyway thanks all for the help and comments, this worked, "Convert.toLeftPaddedString(Convert.toDoubleString(cost, false), 10);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, we don't know what the `Convert` class is, nor what parameters its methods expect.

However, something tells me that instead of...

```
Convert.toLeftPaddedString(Convert.toDoubleString(cost, 10))
```

...you may have meant...

```
Convert.toLeftPaddedString(Convert.toDoubleString(cost), 10)
```

...since the other invocations of `Convert.toLeftPaddedString` do accept an integer argument for the second parameter.

As others have stated, according to the error message, you need to supply a `boolean` second argument to `Convert.toDoubleString`, but that method may be overloaded; we cannot tell without more information.

Comment: i'm using a template from the professor. anyway thanks all for the help and comments, this worked, "Convert.toLeftPaddedString(Convert.toDoubleString(cost, false), 10);"

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are calling the method `Convert.toDoubleString(cost, 10)`. This method expects that you pass it a `double` and a `boolean` as the 2 arguments, but you are giving it a `Double` and an `int` instead.

You therefore need to change the method call to give it the correct values, something like this perhaps...

```
Convert.toDoubleString(cost.doubleValue(), true);
```

The same thing applies to all your other methods, such as `toLeftPaddedString()` - make sure you're giving the correct types to the method.